# como compartir datos entre xibs que esten en el mismo viewController

Tags: ios, swift

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un viewController (en la img es azul)
un xib que es un carrusel y tiene un scroll horizontal (en la img es rojo)
otro xib que tiene un desplazamiento vertical

ambos xibs están en una vista de tabla y cada uno tiene una vista de colección para mostrar los datos, y me gustaría que cuando toque una celda desde el xib rojo, la función didSelectItemAt muestre los datos en el xib verde

¿¿¿alguna idea??? Ya estoy usando protocolos y delegado, pero cuando hago clic en una opción en rojo, el xib verde devuelve cero

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que agregues el código que has intentado con protocolos y delegados para tener una idea del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en el mismo ViewController crea una variable global, asignale los datos y llámala donde la necesites.

Prox. sube el código para tener una visión completa de lo que intentas hacer.